# How to read from an online text file in Java

Tags: java, file, url, text, runtime-error

```
url = new URL("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/userlist.txt?w=c8bdbe4a");  
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
q=s.next();
if(me.equals(q))
    {b=true; break;}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/userlist.txt?w=c8bdbe4a
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at gui.main(gui.java:48)
```

Anyone know why, or how to fix this?  I am trying to read from an online text file.

Comment: Because you are not authorized to access this resource... just enter the URL in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to login to access that file, its not publicly accessible and that is why 403 ERROR CODE

Answer (score 0):

That resource is protected by a password. You are not providing one, thus you cannot access the file. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for a list of HTTP error codes.

Note: 403 - Forbidden.